# Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Does anyone know what the Fourier transform (in the sense of distributions) of 
$$
f(x) = (x^2 - 1)^{1/2}x, \quad |x|\ge 1, 
$$
and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all observe that

$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx} (x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}_+, $$

where  for any real number $t$ we set $t_+=\max(t,0)$.   Thus it suffices  to compute the Fourier  transform of $(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}_+$.

In Section 2.5 Chapter 2  of   the book by Gelfand and Shilov, *Generalized Functions, vol.1, Academic Press 1964*,  the authors  compute the Fourier transform of $(ax^2+bx+c)^\lambda_+$. Your example corresponds to Case (3) discussed there.  More precisely  the Fourier transform of $(x^2-1)^\lambda_+$ is the function

$$\Gamma(\lambda+1)\sqrt{\pi}\left|\frac{\xi}{2}\right|^{-\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\cos\pi(\lambda+\frac{1}{2}) J_{-\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}(|\xi|)-J_{\lambda+\frac{1}{2}}(|\xi|)}{\sin \pi(\lambda+\frac{1}{2})}, $$

where $J_\alpha$ denotes the Bessel function  of order $\alpha$.

Comment: What happens with the $\textrm{sin}\pi (\lambda+1/2)$ for $\lambda=3/2$?

Comment: I thought nobody  was going to ask this embarrassing  questions.  Here are two possible answers. You either let $\lambda\to\frac{3}{2}$ in the above formula or, better yet, consult the above reference where there is an alternate description involving the Bessel functions $N_\alpha$.. I did not include  that formula since I would  have  had to explain  what $N_\alpha$ is.

Comment: Liviu, thank you so much for your response. I believe $N_\alpha $ is the same as $Y_\alpha $, i.e. the Bessel function of the second kind, which is what I got by taking the limit. And thanks Robert for bringing up the discussion of the limiting cases. 

Comment: You are absolutely right.  The label $N_\alpha$ is an old fashion one  that survived mainly behind the Iron Curtain and it reflects the fact that $Y_\alpha=N_\alpha$ is sometime the Neumann function.